# How do I encode a NSString to send it to a PHP iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, nsstring

I need to send a NSString to a PHP file that goes into a MySQL database.
The problem that I have is with especial characters like "é". When I get the string (from the Facebook SDK for iOS) it comes like this: "Thenáme Thesurnamé", for example.

I send it to a PHP on a server using unicode as charset (I also tried with utf8), but in the database it appears with "Ã©" instead of "é".

The encoding of the database is utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: There are several places where you need to specify utf8 in PHP and in MySQL. Make sure the database is utf8, and make sure the connection is utf8, and make sure the table is utf8, and make sure the individual table columns are all utf8. And also make sure the page is using utf8 in the HTTP headers and HTML <meta> tags. Also, there are some PHP functions (htmlentities() is one of them off the top of my head) that will corrupt any utf8 string you give it in PHP, so make sure your code doesn't use any of those

Answer (score 0):

You can always user the  [ampersand](http://www.thesauruslex.com/typo/eng/enghtml.htm) in html to encode such chars.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSString *resStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:[srcStr cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]] encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
```